# Bring to front inactive window

Tags: c#, wpf, window, pinvoke, topmost

I've got two WPF applications. Both of them has a window with `Topmost` property set to `true`. Window of first application is a full-screen window and second app takes only part of the screen. The important thing is also that, the second application can't be activated (activation was blocked by following code):

```
private const int GWL_EXSTYLE = -20;
private const int WS_EX_NOACTIVATE = 0x08000000;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex,int dwNewLong);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd,int nIndex);

protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
{
    WindowInteropHelper helper = new WindowInteropHelper(window);
    SetWindowLong(helper.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(helper.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_NOACTIVATE);
}
```

I'm trying to bring to front second application, when user click on button which is placed on first application. I tried to achieve this by using [SetForegroundWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setforegroundwindow) and [ShowWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow), but it's not working. Do someone have any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
yourSpecificWindow.Activate();
```

if that doesnt do the trick, also include

```
yourSpecificWindow.TopMost = true;
yourSpecificWindow.Focus();
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, unfortunately I forgot to tell you about one important thing - I'm opening second window is not in the same application, I'm running it via `Process.Start()`, so I can't do it this way.
Updated my question.

Comment: Then you you maybe call the second application with commandline arguments are use those to call the above methods?

Comment: It's still not working, because Activation of window is blocked.

Comment: even if you call the other application with commandline parameters?

Comment: Just to be clear: when I start second application, it's beign opened on top of screen, everything is fine. After that, when i click on first app, the second is going under it. I'm trying to reactivate it (send again to top) as I said before, but nothing is working. As a workaround for now I'm just closing second app and turning it on again when i need to reactivate it.

Comment: Did you develop both applications?

Comment: Yes, i'm develop both applications

Comment: Then that becomes simpler, if you can at any point only one instance of your second application, then use a mutex object when you click process start, check if your application is running, if yes, bring it to the front and set it as active,

Comment: mahlatse, my problem is that I don't know how to bring it to front - Activate(), Focus(), ShowWindow(), SetForegroundWindow() methods don't work in this specific case.